# Apache2 sending 404 on not matched subdomain

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, subdomain

How can I send 404 if subdomain is not found? For example if I have something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www
  <all other stuff>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www
  <all other stuff>
</VirtualHost>
```

and open example.com, it opens correct page, if I try with subdomain www.example.com, it opens correctly. However if I try test.example.com (or any other subdomain) it still opens the same page, but I would like to send 404. Looks like very similar question to this one:
[apache2-virtualhosts-and-wildcard-subdomains](https://serverfault.com/questions/529184/apache2-virtualhosts-and-wildcard-subdomains), but I don't find a way to create 404 response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do that with RewriteRule like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```

Don't know if it is the best way to do it, but it works for me.